# Printing in metro apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, printing, windows-runtime

Are there any simple samples of Printing from a TextBox control in a C# Windows 8 Metro app?

I mean I've read the documentation and downloaded the printing sample but, cannot figure them out since there are several different samples within the same solution and it's very confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was this article/blog post about printing that came out just a few days ago. Maybe it will help you:

http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2013/01/20/Printing-from-MVVM-XAML-Windows-8-Store-apps.aspx

Comment: Hi, Filip can you please suggest me any way of printing the RichEditBox content ? Please note RichEditBox content is formatted by user. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea, I haven't worked with printing in WinRT yet.